# Building an Android app for ROS

Tags: android, gradle, robotics, ros

I am following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android/Tutorials/Getting%20Started#Building_An_Android_App) to build and android app for ROS

After I import this in Android studio having following problem, I am using Android studio in windows 7.

```
Error:(66, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:The project 'android_apps' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper fileThe build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Comment: Please include the specific code you are using from the tutorial so this question ages gracefully. It's possible that link might go offline or be moved in the future.

Comment: that's a lot of code, it's in the git repo : )